# how to draw circle in map view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dictionary

hi i wanna draw a circle in map view ( my map is Neshan ) but i can't understand the documantion of
https://platform.neshan.org/android-sdk/reference/1.0.0/doc/org/neshan/mapsdk/model/Circle.html
if anyone draw circle with carto and linestyle can share this piece of code?

public void Draw_Circle() {

```
    Color color=new Color(0x000000);
    Circle circleOptions = new Circle(lastSectedLoc,radius,color,getLineStyle());


   map.addCircle(circleOptions);
}
private LineStyle getLineStyle(){
    LineStyleBuilder lineStCr = new LineStyleBuilder();
    lineStCr.setColor(new Color((short) 2, (short) 119, (short) 189, (short)190));
    lineStCr.setWidth(12f);
    lineStCr.setStretchFactor(0f);
    return lineStCr.buildStyle();
}
```

this is my code i tried to draw circle and it crash

Answer (score 1):

For drawing circle in android map view you can try this:

```
private void drawCircle(LatLng point) {

    // Instantiating CircleOptions to draw a circle around the marker
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
    // Specifying the center of the circle
    circleOptions.center(point);
    // Radius of the circle
    circleOptions.radius(100);
    // Border color of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    // Fill color of the circle
    circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);
    // Border width of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);
    // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

}
```

For reference please refer : [circle in maps](http://www.codeplayon.com/2021/02/how-to-draw-a-circle-around-marker-on-google-map-in-android/)

Comment: tnx for answering.the problem is google map boycotted for Iranian i use Neshan map and CircleOptions isn't work. i should use lineStyle and Circle of carto library

Comment: in that case, you can consider using clusters or heat maps , like this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/heatmap
 does this support your library.

Comment: google things isn't allowed

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your app build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13'
```